# Duplicate of PV dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:96

Tags: linux, oracle, lvm

I have configured multipath in RHEL linux. i have changed the filter to "`filter = [ "a|/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-.*mpath-.*|", "r|.*|"]`". After that while issue a command `vgscan`if diplays a followin error

```
Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:96
  Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:16
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:80
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:0
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:80
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:0
  Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:96
  Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:16
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:80
  Duplicate of PV OLugXq-iONS-X2Zm-JScR-0Khq-SekX-N2IhQl dev /dev/mapper/mpathb exists on unknown device 8:0
  Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:96
  Duplicate of PV TNaeXs-74GB-U2hq-DR8Z-nlJO-UQdQ-rg7hW7 dev /dev/mapper/mpathc exists on unknown device 8:16
  PV /dev/mapper/mpathb    VG lvol0   lvm2 [799.98 GiB / 49.98 GiB free]
  PV /dev/mapper/mpatha1   VG rhel    lvm2 [99.97 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/mapper/mpathc    VG lvol1   lvm2 [49.98 GiB / 1008.00 MiB free]
  Total: 3 [949.94 GiB] / in use: 3 [949.94 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

i have tried lot in modifying lvm filters. 
Could anyone help me on this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Apologies for this. And thanks for the information...

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem on Centos 7.2, I found a solution after searching in the internet.

1. Backup your vg info, then restore the vg info, scan the vg and pv. The annoying info will disappear
2. The operations are

   1. `vgcfgbackup;vgcfgbackup -f /root/vgcfg.backup`
   2. `vgcfgrestore vg01`
   3. `vgscan;pvscan`
   4. `vgdisplay vg01`

The link to the complete solution is here http://www.torrycrass.com/2016/05/18/lvm-duplicate-of-pv-exists-on-unknown-device

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and don't just include a link. Your post should stand alone from any other resource...